# Create an array from csv for use with D3.js library

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

I have this cvs

```
<script id="cur_data" type="text/csv">Russian Federation,Italy,France,Luxembourg,Greece,Japan,Others
293,302,91,7,7,7,53</script>
```

how can I create the array format suitable for d3.js library ?

Answer (score 1):

It would probably be better to keep it as a separate CSV file which you load asynchronously.  So keep your data in `data.csv` and then load it using [`d3::csv()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/CSV#csv) like so:

```
d3.csv("data.csv", function(data){
    console.log(data);
});
```

---

If you *really* want it in a `<script>` tag though, put it in an array or whatever data structure is appropriate.

```
<script>
    var data = [
        {
            country: "Russian Federation",
            value: 293
        },
        {
            country: "Italy",
            value: 302
        },
        {
            country: "France",
            value: 91
        },
        {
            country: "Luxembourg",
            value: 7
        },
        {
            country: "Greece",
            value: 7
        },
        {
            country: "Japan"
            value: 7
        },
        {
            country: "Others",
            value: 53
        }
    ];
</script>
```

Then use the data in whatever function d3.js has.  You don't typically make `<script>` tags with `type="text/csv"`.  You would use `text/javascript` if anything since it's primarily only used for JavaScript.  See [MDN script tag documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-type)

Answer (score 1):

CSV is not easy to parse (optional quotes, escaped char, separator not normalized (tab, comma, semicolon...)) you should use a library for that (d3 have one)

```
var csvSource = document.querySelector("#cur_data").textContent;
var data = d3.csv.parse(csvSource);
```